# How to increase count on variable

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to update a counter but it's getting reset to zero each time the repeat loop starts. The variable in question is myUpDownCnt.

```
on roundThis(n, numDecimals)
    set x to 10 ^ numDecimals
    (((n * x) + 0.5) div 1) / x
end roundThis

on idle
    set myTime to time of (current date) as string
    set myAvg to 1.08
    set myUpDownCnt to 0
    
    repeat until myTime = true
        set myTimeB to (round ((time of date ((current date) as string)) / 60) rounding down) mod 5 = 0 --every 5 minutes
        if myTimeB then
            quit application "Numbers"
            tell application "Numbers" to open POSIX file "/Users/steve 1/Documents/Document.numbers"
            tell application "Numbers"
                tell the table 1 of sheet 1 of document "Document"
                    set myAvg to the value of cell "C57"
                    set myAvgPrior to the value of cell "E57"
                end tell
            end tell
            
            set myAvgDiff to myAvg - myAvgPrior
            set myDiffPercent to myAvg / myAvgPrior - 1
            if myAvgDiff > 0 then
                if myUpDownCnt < 0 then
                    set myUpDownCnt to 1
                else
                    set myUpDownCnt to myUpDownCnt + 1
                end if
                say "Increasing " & myUpDownCnt & " times in a row"
                
            else
                if myAvgDiff = 0 then
                    say "No change."
                else
                    if myUpDownCnt > 0 then
                        set myUpDownCnt to -1
                    else
                        set myUpDownCnt to myUpDownCnt - 1
                    end if
                    say "Decreasing " & -myUpDownCnt & " times in a row"
                end if
            end if
        end if
        return 60 --less than 60 may cause it to get double triggered.
    end repeat
end idle

on quit {}
    display dialog "Are you sure you want to quit?"
    continue quit -- quits the applet
end quit
```

Comment: Thanks @tetsujin that worked perfect. I thought it had something to do with that but wasn't sure of the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifically setting `myUpDownCnt` as a local variable, value `0` at the beginning of each idle function entry.

Instead make it a a global, outside your function, so you only define it once.

```
global myUpDownCnt      -- declare myUpDownCnt
set myUpDownCnt to 0    -- initialize myUpDownCnt

on function ()
    set myUpDownCnt to (myUpDownCnt + 1)
end function
```